# Как оперировать с выведенными данными цикла for?

Tags: c++, циклы, for, while

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int A, B, sum = 0; // A = 9; B = 15
    cin >> A >> B;
    for (int i = A; i <= B; i++) {
        while (i != 0) {
            sum += i % 10;
            i /= 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Мне цикл for выводит 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
Мне нужно оперировать с ними с помощью while
Но while оперирует только с 9 потому что 9!=0
И так бесконечно
**Как оперировать с выводом цикла for?**

Comment: Похоже на ваш вопрос уже есть ответ, но я всё-равно порекомендую вам изучить, как [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = A; i <= B; i++) {
    int j = i;
    sum = 0; // -- ?
    while (j != 0) {
        sum += j % 10;
        j /= 10;
    }
}
```